# Select2 load default Value in single select elements using remote data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

Im using [jquery Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), select2 works perfectly fine. but what i want that when page loads a default value should be loaded from controller.

Yes i already did google and yes this question have been posted many times and i cant quite get my head around it.. so thats why i need help in this.

Here is the select2 js coding:

```
/*----------- Select2 DropDown Common Script  -------------------------*/
//For ServerSide Script
function commonSelect2(selector,url,id,text,minInputLength,placeholder){
    selector.select2({
        minimumInputLength:minInputLength,
        placeholder:placeholder,
        ajax: {
            type:"post",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    term: term, //search term
                    page_limit: 10 // page size
                };
            },
            initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                var data = {id: element.val(), text: element.val()};
                callback(data);
            },
            results: function(data, page) {
                var newData = [];
                $.each(data, function (index,value) {
                    newData.push({
                        id: value[id],  //id part present in data
                        text: value[text]  //string to be displayed
                    });
                });
                return { results: newData };
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here how i calls it from php file

```
{{*The Selector for Selecting the User Group*}}
var selector = $('#selectGroup');
var url = "{{base_url()}}admin/usersManageUsers/loadAllUserGroups/";
var id = "GroupID";
var text = "GroupName";
var minInputLength = 0;
var placeholder = "Select User Group";
commonSelect2(selector,url,id,text,minInputLength,placeholder);
//End of the CommonSelect2 function
```

I have added the `initselection()` function, but i don't know if i did wrote it correctly?

and in end i added this in html select2 hidden input tag.

I have tried to search on net, but looks like i am getting no where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Mistake.
i defined initSelection inside the ajax. Should have defined it outside ajax.

now defined `initSelection()` after the ajax

```
ajax: {
    type:"post",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    quietMillis: 100,
    data: function(term, page) {
        return {
            term: term, //search term
            page_limit: 10 // page size
        };
    },
    results: function(data, page) {
        var newData = [];
        $.each(data, function (index,value) {
            newData.push({
                id: value[id],  //id part present in data
                text: value[text]  //string to be displayed
            });
        });
        return { results: newData };
    }
},
initSelection : function (element, callback) {
    var data = {id: element.val(), text: element.val()};
    callback(data);
}
```